# "attract tourists" vs "attractive to tourists" in the sentence

Tags: word-choice

> 1. The high mountains are attractive to tourists.
> 2. The high mountains attract tourists.

Which word is better to use, attract or attractive?
Please explain the differences between them to me.

Comment: Consider: "The high mountains are a tourist attraction". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourist_attraction

Comment: In sentence 2, we hope your objective is to attract more than one tourist!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I've edited my OP.

Comment: There is a distinction between the two sentences. The first sentence can be interpreted to mean either that high mountains exert a pull on tourists (such as hikers and climbers) or that tourists merely enjoy the scenery, possibly from a distance. The second sentence has the first meaning, that high mountains bring tourists to the area.

Answer (score 2):

> The high mountains are attractive to tourists.

This means that the tourists who visit the high mountains find them attractive.

> The high mountains attract tourists.

This means that the mountains cause tourists to visit.

Hypothetically with the first sentence you could imagine tourists with no plan to visit accidentally stumbling upon the mountains and finding them attractive.

With the second sentence you could imagine tourists planning to visit the mountains because they believe them to be attractive, but when they get there they might not actually find them attractive!